# Loop over finite probability weights with SciPy/NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, probability

Let us have a single event probability `prob` which is a scalar between 0-1. If I want to iterate over every possible probability with 0.1 increments, then I can use:

```
prob = np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.1)
```

Now assume I have 5 events (independent, probabilities sum to 1), each with probability `p_i`. I would like to have multi-dimensional probability arrays such as:

```
1.0 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.0
0.9 - 0.1 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.0
0.9 - 0.0 - 0.1 - 0.0 - 0.0
0.9 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.1 - 0.0
0.9 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.1
0.8 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.0 - 0.0
0.8 - 0.1 - 0.0 - 0.1 - 0.0
.      .     .     .     .
.      .     .     .     .
.      .     .     .     . 
0.2 - 0.2 - 0.2 - 0.2 - 0.2
```

Is there a more clever way than to consider all the combinations of 0 - 0.1 - ... - 1 and delete the rows not summing up to 1? If yes, what is the easiest way?

Comment: should it be np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to generate that probability matrix? Or you already have it and want to delete rows that do not sum to 1?

Comment: @DavidKong I would like to arrange these bounds myself. I don't want to have a zero probability, neither 1-0 = 1.

Comment: @Brenlla thanks for asking. I would like to generate this prob matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and `filter` to create all combinations that sum 10 and pass it to an array:

```
import itertools
f = filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 10, itertools.product(*[range(11)]*5))
x = np.array(list(f)).astype(np.float)/10
x
>> array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 1. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.9],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.8],
       ...,
       [0.9, 0. , 0.1, 0. , 0. ],
       [0.9, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

**EDIT**

For the record, here's a more efficient way without using filtering. Essentially you create `k` bins (in your example, 10), and "assign" them to "n" samples (in your example, 3) in all possible combinations, using `combinations_with_replacement`

Then, you count how many bins each samples gets: this is your probability. This method is more complex to understand but avoids the `filter`, and thus it is much more efficient. You can try it with divisions of 0.01 (`k = 100`)

```
n = 3 # number of samples
k = 100 # number of subdivisions

f = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(3),k) #your iterator
r = np.array(list(f)) #your array of combinations
x = np.vstack((r==i).sum(1) for i in range(n)).T/k #your probability matrix
```

Comment: Do you think it is easy to arrange the break points to be 0.01, etc.

Comment: yes, simply replace `range(11)` by `range(101)`, `sum(x)== 10` by `sum(x)== 100`, and `/10` by `/100`. Warn you, that's a huge matrix!

Comment: That was just out of curiosity, I am not brave enough to run that :)

Comment: I was curious too, since I knew there had to be a way to avoid creating all combinations and filtering them (I think I found it). I and added it to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

There's likely a more elegant solution using itertools but this is probably fine and uses no dependencies?:

```
for i in prob:
  for j in prob:
     for k in prob:
        for l in prob:
           m = 1 - i - j - l
           if m>=0:
              print(i,j,k,l,m)
```